# laravel-mongodb ORDER BY FIELD not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, jenssegers-mongodb

I've been reading some documentations [here](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/master/tests/QueryTest.php) and really not been able to find a solution on how to order the results in a specific order of a field name. NOT ALPHABETICALLY in a descending nor ascending order. Wanted to have this result:

```php
$models = Model::orderByRaw('FIELD(name, "Student", "Beginner", "Professional")')->get();
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: i think `orderByRaw`  is not supported in laravel-mongodb library

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$models = Model::orderByRaw("FIELD(name , 'Student', 'Beginner', 'Professional') ASC")->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Tried this but resulted to "bad sort specification" error.

Comment: Yes. I've already tried this beforehand and it's not working. I guess that this is due to the structure of mongodb's data that's why there's no sorting of fields in a specific order?

Comment: Apparently the jenssegers dosnt have support to the orderbyraw query, in the github there are some issues open that are talking about this.

Comment: That is really unfortunate. Thanks.